# JavaMail - Task ends without errors but no mail is sent

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

recently i've been working on an automatic daily mail sender plus a weekly mail inside two different threads on my project.

The mail server is a MS Exchange (don't remember the version)

When the only daily mail was running, my mails were sent just fine.
Now that i've added another thread for the Weekly mails i have some of these issues:

- Only one of the threads are able to send the email ( never both )
- None of the threads are able to send email

On my logs i don't have evidence of errors, it seems the connection to the smtp server is not the problem and that the mail has been sent, but when i check my mailbox, no mails at all are arrived.

I'll post you the code about my Email class

```
public class Email {

boolean debug = false ;
String smtpServer = null;
int smtpPort = null;
String smtpSender = null;
String smtpUser = null;
String smtpPassword = null;


public Email(){
        smtpServer = Config.SMTP_SERVER;
        smtpPort = Config.SMTP_PORT;
        smtpSender = Config.SMTP_SENDER;
        smtpUser = Config.SMTP_USER;
        smtpPassword = Config.SMTP_PASSWORD;
}



public void postMailAttach( String recipients[], String subject, String message, String filename ) throws MessagingException {


Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 

       Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);


       //SET SERVER FOR MESSAGE
       Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
       msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(smtpSender));



       InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];

       for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++){
         toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
       }

       //SET RECIPIENTS FOR MESSAGE
       msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);    
       //SET SUBJECT
       msg.setSubject(subject);

       //SET BODY PART OF MESSAGE 
       BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
       messageBodyPart.setText(message);

       Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
       messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

       //GET FILES TO ATTACH
       DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
       messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
       //SET FILE NAME
       messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
       msg.setContent(multipart);

        //SEND THE EMAIL
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");    
        transport.connect(smtpServer,smtpPort,smtpUser,smtpPassword);    
        transport.sendMessage(msg,msg.getAllRecipients());    
        transport.close();        

}

public void postMail (String recipients[], String subject, String message) throws MessagingException{

    //Set the host smtp address
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 


// create some properties and get the default Session
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
//session.setDebug(debug);

// create a message
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

// set the from and to address
InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(smtpSender);
msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
}
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);


// Optional : You can also set your custom headers in the Email if you Want
//msg.addHeader("MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");

// Setting the Subject and Content Type
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");    
    transport.connect(smtpServer,smtpPort,smtpUser,smtpPassword);    
    transport.sendMessage(msg,msg.getAllRecipients());    
    transport.close();        


}
```

Thank you in advice for any suggestion.

Comment: I don't see the threads here, but you have said that the problem is in the multithreading usage of this class.

Comment: There are 2 separate threads. Threads are only containers that check when to send the email, wich message, wich subject and wich recipients, nothing more. The sending job is all done on Email class

Comment: Are the both threads sharing same object of `Email` class or each thread creates its own object of `Email` class ?

Comment: Object is not shared, it's created within the 2 threads

Comment: You debug by setting [`session.setDebug(true);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/Session.html#setDebug%28boolean%29). This will print JavaMail logs.

Comment: Both the postMail and postMailAttach methods are creating a Session, although one is using Session.getInstance and the other is using Session.getDefaultInstance.  You always want to use Session.getInstance, and based on the way you're using the Session you can do it once in the constructor for your class, save it in a field, and then use it in each method, even if the methods are called from different threads.  Also, your code isn't handling any exceptions, so you can end up with unclosed connections (Transport objects).

Answer (score 0):

After initializating properties like username, password etc

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
  });
```

hope this would help

Comment: i'll try this and let you know

Comment: write it instead of `Session session = Session.getInstance(props,null);` and delete transport part.

Comment: I've added this part and removed the transport.connect() part but now i receive "Not connected" in the Exception

Comment: I editted my answer. copy them all to your code and make sure, u write username and password

Comment: The Authenticator is absolutely not needed, it just makes the code more complex for no advantage.  And those property settings are fine for Gmail, but this person is using their own Exchange server.